# How to Convert Sprite into Texture

Tags: unity, textures, sprites, materials

I Have image with a sprite and i want to change this image sprite to Texture so that I can assign it to the material And i don't want to keep multiple copies for each image as a sprite and texture.

Is there any way to change sprite to texture at run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// assume "sprite" is your Sprite object
 var croppedTexture = new Texture2D( (int)sprite.rect.width, (int)sprite.rect.height );
 var pixels = sprite.texture.GetPixels(  (int)sprite.textureRect.x, 
                                         (int)sprite.textureRect.y, 
                                         (int)sprite.textureRect.width, 
                                         (int)sprite.textureRect.height );
 croppedTexture.SetPixels( pixels );
 croppedTexture.Apply();
```

this should work for you. you can follow this thread for more info:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/651984/convert-sprite-image-to-texture.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't  need to crop or anything. but from thread you share i got my answer which was "Image.sprite.texture".

Answer (score 2):

For just converting Image's sprite To Texture use this:

> Image.sprite.texture

And this will do the Job.

Thanks [@virtouso](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/62441/virtouso) for sharing the thread.

Answer (score 0):

````cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class SpriteToPNGFile : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Sprite _sprite;
    public Sprite _Sprite => this._sprite;

    [SerializeField] private Texture2D _texturePreview;
    public Texture2D _Name => this._texturePreview;

    public void SaveTexture(Texture2D texture2D)
    {
        this._texturePreview = texture2D;

        byte[] bytes = texture2D.EncodeToPNG();

        string directoryPath = Application.dataPath + "/SpriteToPNGFileOutput";

        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(directoryPath + "/Tex_" + GUID.Generate() + ".png", bytes);

        Debug.Log(bytes.Length / 1024 + "Kb was saved as: " + directoryPath);

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
#endif
    }

    public void SaveSpriteAsTexture(Sprite sprite)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(
            (int)sprite.textureRect.width,
            (int)sprite.textureRect.height
        );

        Color[] pixels = sprite.texture.GetPixels(
            (int)sprite.textureRect.x,
            (int)sprite.textureRect.y,
            (int)sprite.textureRect.width,
            (int)sprite.textureRect.height
        );

        texture.SetPixels(pixels);
        texture.Apply();

        this.SaveTexture(texture2D: texture);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(inspectedType: typeof(SpriteToPNGFile))]
    public class SpriteToPNGFileEditor : Editor
    {
        private SpriteToPNGFile _target;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            this._target = (SpriteToPNGFile)this.target;
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();

            if (GUILayout.Button("Generate PNG"))
            {
                this._target.SaveSpriteAsTexture(sprite: this._target._sprite);
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```
````